# How to calculate/update values for a nested list in python?

Tags: python, nested-lists, nested-for-loop

I'm really stuck at a problem, where I completely don't understand why the output is what it is and not what I expected. I basically want to calculate values for the elements of a nested list which is initialized with only zeros. Here is the code of a simple form of my problem:

```
aa = [[0] * 2] * 2

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(0, 10):
            aa[i][j] += k
```

I expected here the output for "aa" to be: [[45, 45], [45, 45]].

But the output is: [[90, 90], [90, 90]]

How can that be? Any explanation would be helpful. After debugging I saw that Python adds the k always to both lists in the list, although i is for example currently 0.

Comment: Please see the [second note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) under *Notes* that follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the shallow copy of list. `aa = [[0] * 2] * 2` creates shallow copy, try `aa = [[0]*2 for i in range(2)]`

```
aa = [[0]*2]*2

print(aa[0]) #[0,0]
print(aa[1]) # [0,0]

aa[0][0] = 2
aa[0][1] = 2

print(aa[0]) #[2,2]
print(aa[1])  # [2,2] !!

# +-------+-------+
# | aa[0] | aa[1] |
# +-------+-------+
#   |         |
#   |         |
#    \       /
#     [0 , 0]
    
#     Both referring to the same list
#     So whatever operation you do in aa[0] will reflect in aa[1] and vice versa
#     Because effectively they are pointing to same list
#     id(aa[0]) == id(aa[1]) ---> True
```

```py
aa = [[0]*2 for i in range(2)]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(0, 10):
            aa[i][j] += k
```

```
[[45, 45], [45, 45]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-initialize the element when you start the 2nd inner loop.
like so, `aa[i][j]=0`, just after the for iteration starts for variable j.
Then you would get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

K is added to both lists because you used multiplication on elements of the list `aa = [[0] * 2] * 2`. By multiplying by 2, you also reproduced the reference, that's why you get the same result in both lists.

You can use list comprehension to avoid this problem:

```
aa = [[0]*2 for i in range(2)]     # [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(0, 10):
            aa[i][j] += k          # [[45, 45], [45, 45]]
```